# How can I create a Task workflow in Airflow based on a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I would like to create tasks based on a list. For example:

`task_1 >> task_2 >> task_3` based on the list [1, 2, 3]. The idea is that each task should trigger an external dag. DAG_A should trigger DAG_B to start, once all tasks in DAG_B are complete, then the next task in DAG_A should start. It should wait for the last task in DAG_B to succeed before trigger the next task in DAG_A.

To create the tasks, here is my current solution.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

from datetime import datetime


dag = DAG(
    "MY_DAG",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule="@daily",
    catchup=False
)


def ex_func_airflow(i):
    print(i)


tabs = [1, 2, 3]

for i in tabs:
    task_id = f'task_tab_{i}'
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        op_args=[i],
        python_callable=ex_func_airflow,
        dag=dag
    )

task
```

**Update:**

I tried the following, but when `wait_task` starts, it stays running and doesn't trigger `task_2` in DAG_A. DAG_B is TEST_DAG which has the task that must be completed before `task_2` in DAG_A will start. But `wait_task` never triggers task_2 in DAG_A to run.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

from datetime import datetime


dag = DAG(
    "MY_DAG",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule="@daily",
    catchup=False
)

trigger_operator = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='trigger_operator',
    trigger_dag_id='TEST_DAG',
)


def ex_func_airflow(i):
    print(i)

tabs = [1, 2, 3]

previous_task = None

for i in tabs:
    task_id = f'task_tab_{i}'
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        op_args=[i],
        python_callable=ex_func_airflow,
        dag=dag
    )

    if previous_task:
        wait_task = ExternalTaskSensor(
            task_id=f'wait_task_{i}',
            external_dag_id="EXTERNAL_DAG_ID",
            external_task_id=f'external_task_{i}',  
            dag=dag
        )
        trigger_operator >> previous_task >> wait_task >> task
    else:
        task
    previous_task = task
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that each task triggers an external BAG and waits for its completion before moving to the next task, you can use the ExternalTaskSensor operator. This operator waits for a specific external task in another DAY to complete before proceeding.

```
dag = DAG(
    "MY_DAG",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False
)

def ex_func_airflow(i):
    print(i)

tabs = [1, 2, 3]

previous_task = None

for i in tabs:
    task_id = f'task_tab_{i}'
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        op_args=[i],
        python_callable=ex_func_airflow,
        dag=dag
    )
    
    if previous_task:
        wait_task = ExternalTaskSensor(
            task_id=f'wait_task_{i}',
            external_dag_id="EXTERNAL_DAG_ID",
            external_task_id=f'external_task_{i}',  
            dag=dag
        )
        previous_task >> wait_task >> task
    else:
        task
    previous_task = task
```

Is that what you meant or something else ?

```
dag_a = DAG(
    "DAG_A",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False
)

dag_b = DAG(
    "DAG_B",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False
)

def ex_func_airflow(i):
    print(i)

tabs = [1, 2, 3]

previous_task = None

for i in tabs:
    task_id = f'task_tab_{i}'
    
    task_a = PythonOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        op_args=[i],
        python_callable=ex_func_airflow,
        dag=dag_a
    )
    
    if previous_task:
        trigger_dag_b = TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id=f'trigger_dag_b_{i}',
            trigger_dag_id="DAG_B",
            dag=dag_a
        )
        
        wait_dag_b = ExternalTaskSensor(
            task_id=f'wait_dag_b_{i}',
            external_dag_id="DAG_B",
            external_task_id=None,  
            mode='reschedule',  
            timeout=3600,  
            poke_interval=60,
            dag=dag_a
        )
        
        previous_task >> trigger_dag_b >> wait_dag_b >> task_a
    else:
        task_a
    
    previous_task = task_a
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I tried it. It creates the task correctly. But, DAG_A should trigger DAG_B to start, once all tasks in DAG_B are complete, then the next task in DAG_A should start. So really it should wait for the last task in DAG_B to succeed before trigger the next task in DAG_A.

Comment: The wait_task gets stuck in a running state @Serega

Comment: Hi! Sorry for waiting, I have completed my answer.

Comment: I updated again, is that what you meant?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I probably can't help you =(